# Traefik HTTPS use hostname instead to IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a NiFi instance running on Docker, we use a Reverse-Proxy**(Traefik)** to send the requests to the NiFi docker instance.
When my NiFi instance is running on HTTP I am able to reach the NiFi UI from the internet. Considering we wanted to have login option, I was working to setup HTTPS as login auth is not possible on HTTP NiFi instance.The setup is all working when I apply a global level SSL verify skip in the Reverse-Proxy level using insecureSkipVerify, but I would not want to do that and when I am on the normal setup to verify the certificates that are generated by NiFi automatically which is a Self-Signed cert it fails with the following error

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"'500 Internal Server Error' caused by: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.0.2.60 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs","time":"2022-10-21T10:29:18Z"}
```

Also checked the /etc/hosts file

```
root@mynifi:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10.0.2.60       mynifi
```

The issue is when Traefik is acting as the load-balancer it seems to be trying to access the service using IP address instead of Hostname

```
{
  "ForwardURL": {
    "Scheme": "https",
    "Opaque": "",
    "User": null,
    "Host": "10.0.2.60:8443",
    "Path": "",
    "RawPath": "",
    "OmitHost": false,
    "ForceQuery": false,
    "RawQuery": "",
    "Fragment": "",
    "RawFragment": ""
  },
  "Request": "{\"Method\":\"GET\",\"URL\":{\"Scheme\":\"\",\"Opaque\":\"\",\"User\":null,\"Host\":\"\",\"Path\":\"/nifi/\",\"RawPath\":\"\",\"OmitHost\":false,\"ForceQuery\":false,\"RawQuery\":\"\",\"Fragment\":\"\",\"RawFragment\":\"\"},\"Proto\":\"HTTP/2.0\",\"ProtoMajor\":2,\"ProtoMinor\":0,\"Header\":{\"Accept\":[\"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\"],\"Accept-Encoding\":[\"gzip, deflate, br\"],\"Accept-Language\":[\"en-US,en;q=0.5\"],\"Cache-Control\":[\"max-age=0\"],\"Cookie\":[\"__Secure-Request-Token=00c9e232-fb30-44e0-a41e-fc0b5ba6b9b5\"],\"Te\":[\"trailers\"],\"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests\":[\"1\"],\"User-Agent\":[\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0\"],\"X-Forwarded-Host\":[\"example.domain.com\"],\"X-Forwarded-Port\":[\"443\"],\"X-Forwarded-Proto\":[\"https\"],\"X-Forwarded-Server\":[\"d9c0b0e2855e\"],\"X-Proxyhost\":[\"example.domain.com\"],\"X-Proxyport\":[\"443\"],\"X-Proxyscheme\":[\"https\"],\"X-Real-Ip\":[\"143.155.67.98\"]},\"ContentLength\":0,\"TransferEncoding\":null,\"Host\":\"example.domain.com\",\"Form\":null,\"PostForm\":null,\"MultipartForm\":null,\"Trailer\":null,\"RemoteAddr\":\"192.168.52.48:51731\",\"RequestURI\":\"/nifi/\",\"TLS\":null}",
  "level": "debug",
  "msg": "vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: Forwarding this request to URL",
  "time": "2022-10-21T15:23:35Z"
}
```

Is there an option to have the hostname defined within the docker-compose file to be used instead of the IP as my service is accessible using the hostname as I was able to confirm that via the curl command on the docker container.

As the docker containers IP keeps changing each time its redeployed I would really be difficult to generate a certificate with IP of the container.

I tried to use the below labels but I am not sure if its the right one to use in this case

```
- "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):8443"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=mynifi:8443"
```

I wanted to know if I can someway instruct Traefik to make the request using the hostname defined instead of the IP

For example

Traefik calls my service using the IP of the container i.e https://10.0.2.90:8443/nifi

I would prefer to use the hostname and Traefik reaches the container using https://mynifi:8443/nifi

Please do let me know if any additional details are needed

**Docker-Compose.yml file**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    nifi:
        user: root
        hostname: mynifi
        # container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: apache/nifi:latest
        restart: on-failure
        # command:
            # - "--serverstransport.insecureskipverify=true"
        environment:
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=8443
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST=0.0.0.0
            # - NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST_URL
            - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST=$DOCKER_HOST_URL:443
            # - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/nifi,/nifi-docs,/nifi-api,/
            - NIFI_WEB_PROXY_CONTEXT_PATH=/
            - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin
            - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=ctsBtRBKHRAx69EqUghvvgEvjnaLjFEB
            - NIFI_SECURITY.AUTORELOAD.ENABLED=true
            # - NIFI_REMOTE_INPUT_SECURE=false
            # - NIFI_WEB_REQUEST_IP_WHITELIST=$DOCKER_HOST_URL
            # - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
            # - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=myzookeeper:2181
            # - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=30 sec
            # - NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY='12345678901234567890A'
            # - DOCKER_HEALTHCHECK_TEST=curl $DOCKER_HOST_URL/nifi/
        # healthcheck:
        #     test: "${DOCKER_HEALTHCHECK_TEST:-curl $DOCKER_HOST_URL/nifi/}"
        #     interval: "60s"
        #     timeout: "3s"
        #     start_period: "5s"
        #     retries: 5
        volumes:
            - nifi_database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
            - nifi_flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
            - nifi_content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
            - nifi_provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
            - nifi_state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
            - nifi_logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
            - nifi_conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
        networks:
            traefik_webgateway:
        deploy:
            labels:
                # traefik
                - traefik.enable=true
                # service
                - traefik.http.services.nifi-flow.loadbalancer.server.port=8443
                - traefik.http.services.nifi-flow.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
                # - "traefik.http.services.nifi-flow.loadbalancer.serverstransports.insecureskipverify=true"
                # middlewares
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyScheme=https"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyHost=$DOCKER_HOST_URL"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyPort=443"
                - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-headers.headers.customRequestHeaders.X-ProxyContextPath:/"
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectregex.permanent=true"
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):8443"
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=mynifi:8443"
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.headers.sslforcehost=true"
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-redirect.headers.sslhost=mynifi"
                # - "traefik.http.middlewares.nifi-tls.forwardauth.tls.insecureskipverify=true"
                # Routers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.middlewares=nifi-headers
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.service=nifi-flow
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.entrypoints=$TRAEFIK_HTTPS_ENTRYPOINT
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.tls=true
                - traefik.http.routers.nifi-flow.rule=Host(`$DOCKER_HOST_URL`) && PathPrefix(`/nifi`)
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                delay: 120s
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 60s
networks:
  traefik_webgateway:
    external: true
      
volumes:
  nifi_conf: {external: true}
  nifi_database_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_flowfile_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_content_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_provenance_repository: {external: true}
  nifi_state: {external: true}
  nifi_logs: {external: true}
```

**Traefik.toml file**

```
#General
[api]  
    dashboard = true

[metrics]
  [metrics.prometheus]

[ping]

[log]
  level = "DEBUG"
  filepath = "/traefik/logs/traefik/traefik.log"
  format = "json"

[accessLog]
  filePath = "/traefik/logs/access/access.log"
  bufferingSize = 10

#ENTRYPOINTS

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"    
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
        [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
          to = "websecure"
          scheme = "https"  

  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders]
      trustedIPs = ["<IP_Address>"] # f5
    [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]

  [entryPoints.apiDashboard]
    address = ':70000'


    

#MIDDLEWARES
[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.test-retry.retry]
     attempts = 4
  [http.middlewares.https-redirectscheme.redirectScheme]
    scheme = "https"
    permanent = true

#TLS
[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/folder/cert"
  keyFile = "/folder/key"


#PROVIDERS
[providers]
  providersThrottleDuration = 2
  [providers.docker]
    watch = true
    endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault = true
    swarmMode = true
    swarmModeRefreshSeconds = 15
    network = "traefik_webgateway"
  [providers.file]
    filename = "/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
    watch = true
```

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with a [mcve]. Can you show us a minimal `docker-compose.yaml` that reproduces this behavior? It's not really clear from your question how traefik is configured, or how your container is configured, etc.

Comment: Hey @larsks thanks for the comment, I have added the files requested. Please do let me know if you need more information I can provide